# How to run existing meanjs project on mac pc?

Tags: macos, meanjs

I have two meanjs projects created on my mac pc using terminal command prompt. One is New1 and another is Old1. but when I run command 'grunt' on terminal then only newly created New1 is running.

I am new at meanjs development that's why I don't know how to run my old meanjs projects on mac pc.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in the generator/scaffolder that you used. But for yeoman based projects exists the convention of use:

grunt serve: For development preview of the app with livereload.

grunt test: For test running.

grunt: For production build of the app.

With Projects managed by Gulp task runner it is the same but replacing grunt command with gulp command.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I have figured out my problem. 
I need to point the directory to the expected project directory then need to run the 'grunt' command on terminal then the expected project will be started.